# Here Maps routing, trying to get around a "Error is NGEO_ERROR_GRAPH_DISCONNECTED"

Tags: here-api

on a very specific set of waypoints imported into Here Maps calculate route, I get the error "NGEO_ERROR_GRAPH_DISCONNECTED". the waypoints don't seem to be incorrect at all, but off the road a bit.

- waypoint0: "27.90157,-82.71284"
- waypoint1: "27.90155,-82.71286"
- waypoint2: "27.90154,-82.71284"
- waypoint3: "27.90158,-82.71284"
- waypoint4: "27.90103,-82.71250"

API URL
[https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.31.0&apikey={APIKEY}&mode=balanced%3Btruck&representation=display&requestId=trackedRoute&waypoint0=27.90157%2C-82.71284&waypoint1=27.90155%2C-82.71286&waypoint2=27.90154%2C-82.71284&waypoint3=27.90158%2C-82.71284&waypoint4=27.90103%2C-82.71250](https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.31.0&apikey=%7BAPIKEY%7D&mode=balanced%3Btruck&representation=display&requestId=trackedRoute&waypoint0=27.90157%2C-82.71284&waypoint1=27.90155%2C-82.71286&waypoint2=27.90154%2C-82.71284&waypoint3=27.90158%2C-82.71284&waypoint4=27.90103%2C-82.71250)

added context this isn't all the waypoints I just trimmed it down to the ones giving me trouble and this is using the vue js packages for Here Map

I'm wondering if there anyway to get around this where the calculation just ignores the waypoints to allow the other points to still be plotted.

Answer (score 0):

We are checking this case with our SDK Team, so it seems this is replicable, and we will check this out, meanwhile, we suggest if you are having this kind of issue with specific waypoints for a route, first check them by using our Route Matching Example: https://demo.support.here.com/examples/v3.1/rme_basic
https://demo.support.here.com/examples/v3/rme_basic

We hope this information is helpful for you.